# Maximum value of $abc$ for $a, b, c > 0$ and $ab + bc + ca = 12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math

$a,b,c$ are three positive real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=12$.

Then find the maximum value of $abc$

Comment: Apply AM-GM inequality?

Comment: Note that $(ab)(bc)(ca)=(abc)^2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applying the inequality $AM \ge GM $ on {$ab,bc,ca$}, we get:
$$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3} \ge (a^2.b^2.c^2)^{\frac13}$$
$\Rightarrow$ $(abc)^{\frac23} \le \frac{12}{3} = 4$

i.e. the maximum value of abc is $4^{\frac32}$ = $8$.

Also, maximum value of $8$ is attained for $a=b=c=2$

Comment: This is Pedro's Answer!

Comment: You have shown $abc$ can be no larger than $8$, now show it can be as large as $8$.

Comment: As G. H. Faust noted, you have to show that equality can occur. It is obvious, but it's worth saying.

Comment: @G.H.Faust The Chakraborty's answer is correct and complete. Since $abc\le 8$, isn't obvious that $\max(abc)=8$? The question itself is only asking the $\max(abc)$ when $ab+bc+ac=12$.

Comment: @V-Moy it's clear that the constraint $ab + bc + ac = 12$ implies $8$ is an upper bound for $abc$. Use of such a general inequality could easily produce a less than ideal upper bound, here it happens to be the least upper bound. It _is_ obvious given a simple trial: symmetry of the bound and $abc$ suggests $a=b=c$, and this works.

Comment: @G.H.Faust For me, it's already clear that $abc$ can be as large as 8 since from AM-GM we get $abc$ is less than or **equal** to 8. Case closed!

Comment: @V-Moy That is a misunderstanding of the less than or equal to relation. Let me change your emphasis a little: less than **or** equal to. See my point? If not, an example. $\forall x : f(x) := x-x^2 \leq 2$. Every value the function takes on is less than $2$, so it satisfies half of "less than or equal to", which is enough to satisfy the relation, since it's an _or_ statement. However, $\max \{ f(x) \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @G.H.Faust Hmm, the question states $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}_+$, but $x-x^2\le 2$ yields $x\notin\mathbb{R}_+$. ヅ

Answer (score 0):

Or, the same answer also comes by intuition. since a,b,c are positive numbers, $(ab).(bc).(ca)$ is maximum only when $ab=bc=ca=\frac{12}{3}=4$. therefore, $ abc={((ab)(bc)(ca))}^\frac{1}{2}=4^\frac{3}{2}=8$.

Comment: Why do we care that ab+bc+ca is maximum?

Comment: @CalvinLin, exactly the same question here.

Comment: @CalvinLin ditto

Comment: @reo I am not being able to recognize the intuition.

Comment: i made a little mistake in my answer, sorry!

Comment: what i intended was that suppose that a+b+c=k(come constant), then the maximum value of abc occurs when a=b=c.
this is similar when we consider a parallelogram with constant perimeter given. the one with the highest area is always the square because the sides are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand that. Same for any number can make this combination.

equation:   $XY+XZ+YZ=N$

Solutions in integers can be written by expanding the number of factorization: $N=ab$

And vospolzovavschis solutions of Pell's equation: $p^2-(4k^2+1)s^2=1$

$k$ - what some integer number given by us.

Solutions can be written:

$X=ap^2+2(ak+b+a)ps+(2(a-2b)k+2b+a)s^2$

$Y=2(ak-b)ps+2(2ak^2+(a+2b)k+b)s^2$

$Z=bp^2-2(2b+a)kps+(4bk^2-2ak-b)s^2$

And more:

$X=-2bp^2+2(k(4b+a)+b)ps-2((4b+2a)k^2+(2b-a)k)s^2$

$Y=-(2b+a)p^2+2(k(4b+a)-b-a)ps-(8bk^2-(4b+2a)k+a)s^2$

$Z=bp^2-2(2b+a)kps+(4bk^2-2ak-b)s^2$

Perhaps these formulas for someone too complicated.

Then equation:  $XY+XZ+YZ=N$

If we ask what ever number: $p$

That the following sum can always be factored: $p^2+N=ks$

Solutions can be written.

$X=p$

$Y=s-p$

$Z=k-p$

8 - really is the maximum number of turns. But the smallest one can hardly get.

Comment: I was wrong decisions can be infinitely many. For example:$N=12$   $X=17$  :  $Y=-24$  :  $Z=-60$

Comment: That's interesting. To these formulas do not like it though he understands how they should get?